# Create large system of inequalities by substituting coefficients from intervals

Tags: list-manipulation, inequalities

I have given statements for example:

- $ax + by < c_1$
- $cx + by + dz < c_2$

And I want to create larger system of inequations in such a way (suppose
variables $x,y,z$ from intervals): I replace all variables $x,y,z$ for all of the possible upper/lower bounds from given intervals.

Simple example:
Given:

- $ax + by < c_1$
- $cx + by < c_2$
- $x$ is elem from $(-10, 10)$, $y$ from $(-5, 5)$

Goal: Get this new system:

- $-10a - 5b < c_1$
- $10a - 5b < c_1$
- $-10a + 5b < c_2$
- $10a + 5b < c_2$
- And solve this system for variables $a,b$ and given constants $c_1, c_2$.

Is any way how to automatize this step in mathematica, that I type the given
inequations, intervals and get this new system and solve it?
This example is very simple but in larger systems it is mad to do it manually
(the all possible combinations rise very quickly).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Should `ax + by < c1` and `cx + by < c2` actually be `a x + b y < c1` and `a x + b y < c2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Table` does the trick:

```
Table[{a x + b y < c1, c x + d y < c2}, {x, {-10, 10}}, {y, {-5, 5}}]
```

Don't forget the inner curly brackets in the specifications for `x` and `y`. This guarantees that only the boundary values get substituted instead of -10, -9, -8, ..., 9, 10. (The bounds don't need to be integers.)

Note that the equations come grouped into various nested lists, which is not what you will want:

> {{{-10 a - 5 b < c1, -10 c - 5 d < c2}, {-10 a + 5 b < 
>       c1, -10 c + 5 d < c2}}, {{10 a - 5 b < c1, 
>      10 c - 5 d < c2}, {10 a + 5 b < c1, 10 c + 5 d < c2}}}

This is easily fixed using `Flatten` on the result.

```
Flatten[Table[{a x + b y < c1, c x + d y < c2}, {x, {-10, 10}}, {y, {-5, 5}}]]
```

> {-10 a - 5 b < c1, -10 c - 5 d < c2, -10 a + 5 b < c1, -10 c + 5 d < 
>     c2, 10 a - 5 b < c1, 10 c - 5 d < c2, 10 a + 5 b < c1, 
>    10 c + 5 d < c2}

This is ready for the various `*Solve` commands.

It's not clear from your question what the rule for choosing `c1` or `c2` is. This generates all 8 combinations, so some of them will be superfluous, but they shouldn't do any harm.